# How can I get express js to read forms

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get nodeJS/expressJS to get a form data sent using the jQuery `$.ajax` function. I know that `$http` is there plus its not a good practice to have angular with jQuery but I am really stuck in something that requires the new form element and jQuery, so I have written this to test it.

I am doing this test because I could not find a way or an info on how to get the form data (including files) without using body-parser as it doesn't support multipart/form-data as I have read some where on the web.

Here is the code in in front end

```
    $scope.sendMsg = function () {
    var formData = new FormData($('#form'));    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/test',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, status,something) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                console.log('data: ' + data);
                console.log('status: ' + status);
                console.log('something: ' + something);
                $scope.msgs.push({content : data})
                $scope.msgText = '';
            });
        },
        error: function (data, error) {
            alert('Did not work');
        }
    });
}
```

and the very basic test in the back end

```
app.post('/test',function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.body.msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `body-parser` for grabbing the input variables and then something like [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) for file parsing. The reason why you need to do this is because the nodejs culture is to put everything into its smallest components so that people can mix and match modules against their needs. In this case you need file parsing and the rest of the form data, so you need to include both middlewares.

The body parser module used to include file parsing functionality but it was deprecated as it used back techniques with temporary files (and the users tended to just use other modules instead).